# Почему не работает callback?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Не выводиться second().

```
 function first(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(1);
        })
    }

    function second(){
        console.log(2)
    }

    first(second);
    //second();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function first(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1);
    cb();
  });
}

function second() {
  console.log(2)
}

first(second);
```